# Postgres CloudSQL Migration: ERROR: permission denied to set parameter "log_min_duration_statement"

Tags: postgresql, migration, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to use the Database Migration Service to migrate an existing database into CloudSQL.

When I start the migration, I receive the following error:

```
finished setup replication with errors: [api_production]: error importing schema: failed to restore schema: stderr=pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC: pg_restore: from TOC entry 3997; 0 0 DATABASE PROPERTIES api_production postgres pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: permission denied to set parameter "log_min_duration_statement" Command was: ALTER DATABASE api_production SET log_min_duration_statement TO '500ms'; pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1 , stdout=
```

How can I continue the migration, ignoring the `SET PARAMETER` statement?

Comment: "Database Migration tool" is a pretty generic name.  Is this some specific tool you are talking about?  Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: I got the name slightly incorrect - it should be "Database Migration Service" https://cloud.google.com/database-migration

Comment: Please try to remove this parameter command , if it is not required during the replication while the data migration job is running, so when the command is called it ignores this step.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to remove the parameter command?
All I have done is pressed the "Start" button.

Comment: @HaydenBall ,You can try to remove the **parameter instead of command** from the **source database** if that is an option, as this seems the parameter `log_min-duration_statement` set to certain value which is being translated to the `ALTER DATABASE` statement when migration service is running.
Another way you can try is to configure the parameter as a flag in the destination database setup under Optional configurations -https://screenshot.googleplex.com/5L4CrcYa3Gsyg45 and see if that helps.

Comment: The source database does not have `log_min_duration_statement` set in config. If I run `SHOW log_min_duration_statement` in the source database, the result is `-1`. I can't see the screenshot you've attempted to send there as it requires a login, but I have tried setting the `log_min_duration_statement` flag in the destination database using the `flags` option in cloud console and this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally been able to start the migration by resetting the parameters on the source database (setting them to match was insufficient).

This can be done from a postgres console on the source database:

```
reset log_min_duration_statement;
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> RESET log_min_duration_statement;
ALTER DATABASE postgres RESET log_min_duration_statement;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Database Migration Service is a managed Google Cloud service, it has restricted access to certain system procedures and tables that require [advanced privileges](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions).The 'postgres' user is the most privileged user available in Cloud SQL, but it is not a Postgres superadmin. See public docs for more information about [PostgreSQL Users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users).
There are some other parameters that you could run the "ALTER Database" command to change; however, "log_statement" and "log_min_duration_statement" are unfortunately not examples of these parameters.
The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-alterdatabase.html) also documents this in particular "Certain variables cannot be set this way, or can only be set by a superuser."
However, you can change the particular setting in Console via the Flags on the database edit screen and remove these statements from the Migration job,to avoid these failure errors.
Please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags) to know more about configuring database flags.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the parameter. I don't care what the value of the parameter is - I just want the database to replicate.

This is happening while the migration service is attempting to replicate the database.

I have also tried setting the flag to match and it does not solve the problem.